# doGet() method of servlet not able to receive parameters sent from a jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am trying to send a parameter to a Servlet from a jsp file.This is the jsp file.

> BookData.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="images/First.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<select onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
<option>
<%out.println(session.getAttribute("name")); %></option>
<option value="SignOut">Sign Out</option>
<option value="#" >Cart</option>

</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleSelect(elm)
{
window.location = elm.value+".jsp";
}
</script>
</div>
<hr>
<% 
try{
    System.out.println("entering BookData.jsp");
        final Connection conn=ConnManager.getInstance().getConnection();

                String bid=request.getParameter("bid");//retrieving bid
                System.out.println("value of bid is "+bid);
        String q="select * from asad.book where bid=?";


         PreparedStatement pstmt=(PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(q);
            pstmt.setString(1,bid);
        ResultSet rs =(ResultSet) pstmt.executeQuery(); 
        String title,url,genre,author,cost,description,seller;
        while(rs.next()){
            title=rs.getString(2);
            url=rs.getString(3);
            genre=rs.getString(4);
            author=rs.getString(5);
            cost=rs.getString(6);
            description=rs.getString(7);
            seller=rs.getString(8);
            out.println("<img src="+ url + "style"+"=width:350px;height:350px>"+"</a>");

            HttpSession sess=request.getSession();
            sess.setAttribute("bookid",bid);

          String urltoSend="/Summer/OrderDetails.java";
            %>
            <h1><%=title %></h1>
                       <span>
                           <span>Title : </span><%=title %><br>
                           <span>Genre :  </span><%=genre %><br>
                           <span>Author : </span><%=author %>

                           <br><center><a href=<%=urltoSend %> >
                           BUY NOW</a></center>
                           <span>Cost : </span><%=cost %><br>
                           <span>Seller : </span><%=seller %><br>
                           <span>Description : </span><%=description %><br>
                        </span>
                        <% 

            }
            }catch(Exception e){}

 %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now to receive the parameters here is the Servlet `OrderDetails.java`.

```
@WebServlet("/OrderDetails")
public class OrderDetails extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public OrderDetails() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("inside try of orderdetails");
        final Connection conn=(Connection) ConnManager.getInstance().getConnection();
        Statement s=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        String username=(String) session.getAttribute("name");
        String q="select * from asad.user where username=?";
         PreparedStatement pstmt=(PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(q);
            pstmt.setString(1,username);
        ResultSet rs =(ResultSet) pstmt.executeQuery(); 
        int cost=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(6));
        //String bid=request.getParameter("id");
        String bid=(String) session.getAttribute("bookid");
         String query="insert into asad.orders(bid,username,cost)"+
                    " values('"+bid+"','"+username+"','"+cost+"')";
            int x=s.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("inserted into orders table");//inserted into orders table
        }catch(Exception e)
        {}
        }


    }
```

But i am browser gives `requested resource not available` error .I am unable to understand why  ?

Comment: Kindly show where is the "id" field on the jsp

Comment: Have you created `servlet` and `servlet mapping` for the orderdetail servlet in web.xml file?

Comment: This is the statement which receives `id` from another jsp `BookSearch.jsp` `String bid=request.getParameter("bid");//retrieving bid`

Comment: I am using annotations  then what's the need to make entry in the web.xml file.`OrderDetails` is the URL pattern of `OrderDetails.java`

Comment: You can set parameter in jsp session and get it in servlet via get session attribute.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the Servlet because even the first `print` statement `System.out.println("inside try of orderdetails");` is not coming on the console.

Comment: How to pass the url pattern of servlet inside `<a>` tag ?

Comment: If you type in the browser with the detail url like OrderDetails?id=123, can you get a correct output from console?

Comment: Might help if you include relevant code from servlet esp. the mapping annotation

Comment: OK i am editing my question.

Comment: *"I am unable to understand why ?"* ... OK. Apparently you dont need any more help. Thats good i guess.

Comment: Your link doesn't provide any parameter... **String urltoSend="/Summer/OrderDetails.java";** If this is the one causing problem. I have to admit that this code is UNREADABLE

Comment: @ AxelH ,earlier i wrote  `String urltoSend="/Summer/OrderDetails.java?id="+bid;`  this but it didn't work that why i changed it.